# nested groupplots

Tags: groupplots

What is the best way to make a `groupplot` of a few `groupplot`s?

I'll need to be able to add tick-labels to both "levels" (the inner and outer `groupplot`s, think Inception 2010).

[image]

For example, each red/blue square is a plot. Each 5x5 pane is a `groupplot` of these plots. The whole thing is a `groupplot` of these 3x3 `groupplot`s (this figure was done by generating PNGs for each of the 5x5 panes and inserting these with `\addplot graphics` to a single `groupplot`).

Comment: At the lowest level, there are no ticks of labels.  You just have an array of squares, with a few labels added after.  So instead of groupplot I would use matrix.

Comment: You mean in my example? Yea, I wish though I could add ticks to at least one plot, to show the ranges of the values there. But, can matrices be nested?

Comment: Oops, it worked but I got an error message "You cannot nest pdfmatrix environments."  Interestingly, I can't use matrix inside \savebox either.

Comment: You don't need to nest the matices, you just need the add a gap here and there.